# Pinterest PDK createPin(...) issue

Tags: android, pinterest, pdk

While creating a new pin using PDK's createPin() method for Android app,

> public void createPin(String note, String boardId, String imageUrl,
>   String link, PDKCallback callback)

it throws error response with error code 400, With no proper error message. 
Below is the code that I have been using.

```
String note = "Hello World!";
String boardID = "130323051656269527";
String imgURL = "https://www.instagram.com/p/BXB_J-mld0Z/?taken-by=chelseasmakeup";
PDKClient.getInstance().createPin(note, boardID, imgURL,null,
                    new PDKCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(PDKResponse response) {
                            Log.e("TAG", "response: " + response.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(PDKException exception) {
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
```

There is nothing worng with the boardID as other api with same boardID works fine. Just creating new pin fails. I couldn't find the solution for this one.

Here is the Log

```
PDK POST: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/ 
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/?access_token=AX4CNtTbNh5ftBz7W1gIcr8gpNFQFNW6RGIDvLtEMpH7NmBEFgAAAAA

com.pinterest.android.pdk.PDKException
07-29 12:19:35.320 2316-2316/com.simplify360.suit.testapp W/System.err:     at com.pinterest.android.pdk.PDKCallback.onErrorResponse(PDKCallback.java:28)
07-29 12:19:35.320 2316-2316/com.simplify360.suit.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:598)
07-29 12:19:35.320 2316-2316/com.simplify360.suit.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:101)
07-29 12:19:35.320 2316-2316/com.simplify360.suit.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
07-29 12:19:35.320 2316-2316/com.simplify360.suit.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-29 12:19:35.320 2316-2316/com.simplify360.suit.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-29 12:19:35.320 2316-2316/com.simplify360.suit.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
07-29 12:19:35.320 2316-2316/com.simplify360.suit.testapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-29 12:19:35.321 2316-2316/com.simplify360.suit.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
07-29 12:19:35.321 2316-2316/com.simplify360.suit.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

> if (!Utils.isEmpty(link)) params.put("image_url", imageUrl);

with

> if (!Utils.isEmpty(imageUrl);)) params.put("image_url", imageUrl);

Later when you are passing the image URL, make sure the URL has an extension as like "http://goldwallpapers.com/uploads/posts/blue-tiger-wallpaper/blue_tiger_wallpaper_001.jpg." URL like "https://www.instagram.com/p/BUAs-jVF9Fx/?taken-by=chelseasmakeup" didn't work.